# Regex javascript match the second letter by the first letter, but the second letter must be an uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex matches the second letter by the first letter, but the second letter is not an uppercase

```
([a-z])\1
```

Now regex matches letters like aa or bb,... but I need that my regex can match all aA,bB,... from this string "abc`aA`cv`bB`kl`mM`"

So how to make that regex can match the second value by the first value, but the second must be an uppercase

Comment: Please provide some sample data to make it more obvious what you are trying to match. For example, is `aA` the entire string, or just a part of it?

Comment: @Nick I provide some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could phrase this by matching all `[a-z]\1` in lowercase mode and then checking if each match also matches `[a-z][a-Z]`:

```js
var input = "abcaAcvbBklmMzzQQ";
var matches = input.match(/([a-z])\1/gi)
                   .filter(x => /^[a-z][A-Z]$/.test(x));
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: @Nick I get the doubt...the OP used "first" and "second" letter, leading me to think that this should be happening at the start of the word.  But yes, no actually patterns were given.

Comment: I've VTC'ed as unclear...

Comment: OP has edited and the match occurs in the string, not at the beginning...

Comment: @Nick I have made an update above.

Comment: Nice and succinct!

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly as, but if you must use a simple regex, you could just brute-force the full set of pairings:

```
var myText = "aAaaABbCCddEEeEfF";
var letterPairs = myText.match(/aA|bB|cC|dD|eE|fF|gG|hH|iI|jJ|kK|lL|mM|nN|oO|pP|qQ|rR|sS|tT|uU|vV|wW|xX|yY|zZ/g);
console.log(letterPairs);
```

It doesn't feel very satisfactory as a solution, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: The man's not wrong... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with *just* a JavaScript regular expression *(well, not unless you [list all possible combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72300780/157247))*. Regular expressions in some other environments may be able to do it, but not JavaScript's.

It's fairly straight-forward, though, to match a lower-case character followed by an upper-case character and then filter out ones where the one isn't the lower-case equivalent of the other:

```js
const str = "abcaAcvbBklmM";

const results = [];
for (const [, lower, upper] of str.matchAll(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g)) {
    if (lower === upper.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
        results.push(lower + upper);
    }
}

console.log(results);
```

How that works:

- The regular expression `/([a-z])([A-Z])/g` matches a lower-case letter followed by an upper-case letter (but they aren't necessarily the "same" letter), capturing each in a capture group.
- `matchAll` matches all occurrences of that in a string, returning an iterator for the results.
- The `for-of` loop loops through the results from the iterator. The results from `matchAll` are an augmented array,¹ where the first element in the array is the overall match, followed by elements for any capture groups. The code uses destructuring in the `for-of` to pick out the second and third elements of the array (the two capture groups).
- If the first letter matches the second letter converted to lower case, it's  a match and we retain it.

We can also do this with multiple passes using array methods rather than a single `for-of`:

```js
const str = "abcaAcvbBklmM";

const results = [...str.matchAll(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g)]
    .filter(([, lower, upper]) => lower === upper.toLocaleLowerCase())
    .map(([match]) => match);

console.log(results);
```

---

¹ This code isn't using the augmented parts of the array, but basically it addition to being an array it has an `index` property saying where the match occurred, a `groups` property containing capture group information (which we could have used, but it was just as easy to use the array elements for this simple regex), and an `input` property with the original string.

Comment: Some regex engines support `([a-z])\U\1`, which would exactly match what the OP wants.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Exactly, that's what I was saying in my first paragraph. JavaScript's doesn't, but some (or even many) others do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the capture group with the backreference and make the pattern case insensitive with the `/i` flag.

Then compare the matched string with the expected lower and uppercase variants.

```js
const input = "yyabcaAcvbBklmMzzQQ";
const regex = /([a-z])\1/ig;

const matches = input.match(regex)
  .filter(s =>
    s[0].toLowerCase() + s[1].toUpperCase() === s
  )

console.log(matches);
```